# Blank space on right side of screen with XMonad/Gnome

Tags: gnome, xmonad

Fresh install of 11.10 x64. I set up XMonad with gnome-session as I did before on 11.04, following the guide on the Arch wiki. Everything works, but there's this weird vertical space about the size of a scrollbar on the side of the screen. <strike>The space is also above xmobar (the battery system tray icon is hidden behind it and I can't click it).</strike>

[XMonad weird space (since I can't post images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W58XH.jpg)

Is there some weird XMonad or Gnome option I'm missing? I don't even know where to begin to look.

Comment: shortly after this i got fed up with ubuntu and switched to arch, which just uses a stock gnome 3. clearly, this isn't a solution, but this post deserved an update. i've also switched from trayer to stalonetray, which seems to integrate better with xmobar.

Answer (score 3):

Something is setting `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` to block that part of the screen.  For me it was *trayer*.

If you're using *trayer* try using `--SetPartialStrut false` to see if that fixes it.  If not you'll have to track down what is setting it.  If you're using *trayer* on the same edge as *xmobar* that sets the correct edge as blocked already, so even though technically things could go on top of trayer they won't since xmobar will block that space.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the edge at giving up on Ubuntu just like you and I am a returning Linux user..so not a total newbie. As always,the most elegant solution is the simplest one. In my case `cvt` generated wrong data, which I just discovered after few days of headaches.

In short, you will have to use `xvidtune` to generate new numbers, which you will have to insert either in your `xorg.conf` or `xrandr` command line tool. If inserting in `xorg.conf` you should have similar line in your Monitor Section:

```
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1284 1420 1712  1024 1025 1028 1064  -HSync +Vsync
```

If using `xrandr` to change resolution you should use something like this:

```
xrandr --newmode your_choice_of_name 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120
xrandr --addmode VGA1 your_choice_of_name
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode your_choice_of_name
```

Of course, changing the numbers with the one from `xvidtune`.

I just hope I helped somebody, because I spent many hours trying to resolve that problem and couldn't seem to find solution to it.
Good luck.